# Which program is preventing FileZilla from connecting to the server?

Tags: filezilla

At first, I had no problem with FileZilla connecting to the server, but recently when I try to connect to any server, FileZilla shows me this error message:

```
Status: Connecting to 92.222.103.103:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 92.222.103.103:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Connecting to 92.222.103.103:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I think a program is using the same port and not allowing FileZilla to connect.

Comment: Sounds like port 21 is closed on the server you're trying to reach, or the machine is down. Can you ping it?

Comment: Pinging 92.222.103.103 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 92.222.103.103: bytes=32 time=1812ms TTL=42
Reply from 92.222.103.103: bytes=32 time=469ms TTL=42
Reply from 92.222.103.103: bytes=32 time=281ms TTL=42
Reply from 92.222.103.103: bytes=32 time=163ms TTL=42

Comment: OK, try FTPing in from the command line (ftp 92.222.103.103, then provide user name and password). If you can connect, clear FTP is working.

Comment: I can't connect in command line and show this message after long time :
Connection closed by remote host.

Comment: I can connect to this server with net2ftp.com, but i can't with filezilla and ...

Comment: Are you in charge of the server, or is it with a hosting company?

Comment: Server don't has any problem. any server not connected in filezilla. I think a program prevent that

Comment: Which Filezilla version do you use? I had the same problem w/ Filezilla 3.10.x IIRC, downgrading to 3.9.x did the trick.

Comment: I use version 3.9.0.2. I use kaspersky internet security too. I think Kaspersky prevents filezilla connecting to server, but i don't know how solve this problem. I use KIS 15.